# Ajax call start loading like a freak

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a site for testing Ajax... and it works:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="AJAX.aspx.cs" Inherits="HB___test.AJAX" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Ajax() {
            var xmlHttp;
            try {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("No AJAX!?");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                setTimeout('Ajax()', 10000);
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax-Content.aspx", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout('Ajax()', 10000);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    Kummefryser...!
    <div id="chat" class="fisk" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the site it's laoding:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajax-Content.aspx.cs" Inherits="HB___test.ajax_Content" %>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbChat" runat="server" Rows="10" Width="400px"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And the codebehind for the above site:

```
public partial class ajax_Content : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        grjenie31Entities gr;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gr = new grjenie31Entities();

            var query = from es in gr.chats
                        where es.id > ((from esh in gr.chats select esh.id).Max() - 15)
                        orderby es.timestamps descending
                        select es;

            List<chat> list = new List<chat>();
            foreach (chat chat in query)
            {
                list.Add(chat);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                lbChat.Items.Add("[" + list[i].timestamps + "] " + list[i].personID.ToString() + ": " + list[i].besked);
            }
            this.lbChat.SelectedIndex = this.lbChat.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
```

But when I load the site ajax-Content.aspx it start reloading freakingly fast... so in 30 seconds I can't read the text it load in the ajax.Content.aspx site.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange fires not only on success, you should only start the new timeout on readystate 4

furtherMore you should define a variable for the timeout to be able to clear an existing timeout before running a new.